# Checkboxes not "checking" - trying to read someone else's code

Tags: forms, html, checkbox

I am trying to read someone else's code (they're on vacation), and they're using HTML 5 which I am less familiar with.

For some reason, when I click the checkboxes, they aren't selecting.

Here's the code:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>I would like a quote on the following products:</legend>
<div class="divider">
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Selective Pallet Rack – Roll Formed" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Roll Formed Selective Pallet
</h3>
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Selective pallet Rack – Structural" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Structural Selective Pallet
</h3>
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Drive In / Drive Thru Rack" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Drive In / Drive Thru Rack
</h3>
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">Other</h3>
<textarea name="Other_Products"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="divider">
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Push Back Rack" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Push Back Rack
</h3>
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Pallet Flow Rack" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Pallet Flow Rack
</h3>
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Cantilever Rack" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Cantilever Rack
</h3>
<h3 style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" value="Safety Products" name="Quote_on_Products[]">
Safety Products
</h3>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Could it be the h3 tag? The values containing odd characters? I'm at a loss as to why it wouldn't allow me to click a checkbox.

Comment: What browser are you testing in ?

Comment: You haven't given enough to reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vUJxp/

Comment: Testing in Chrome and Firefox. Same issue in both.

Comment: I have no problem checking the boxes in Chrome, Safari, Firefox or Opera. Do you get the problem when trying on http://jsfiddle.net/vUJxp/? Are you clicking the actual box and not the text?

Comment: Even I have no problems checking the checkboxes. You might be having some other JS code which might be preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug code you didn't write and have never seen before. You might want to check any relevant javascript files that could be preventing the checkboxes from being checked. Click event handlers can be added dynamically on page load from a js file, and those handlers could be doing almost anything, including messing with your checkboxes.

Comment: Only Javascript I see is this:  <script src="javascripts/libs/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>

Comment: Scratch that. Just noticed something that might be the culprit.

Comment: Could it be that the <H3>s pretend to be <label>s? HTML5 is not _that_ different from HTML4...

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the Html. I have created JSFiddle with your Html and I am able to check checkboxes. Here is the JsFiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/zDwkH/

As ean5533 rightly pointed out, check if there is any javascript that is preventing these checkboxes from being checked.

Answer (score 0):

If button events are not working, find out what's happening. Use either firebug, or IE (believe it or not) to find out what the current onclick event is. If it the code has return false at the end of it, this is why it is apparently 'doing nothing'.

**But**, also consider that it could be a rendering issue. For instance if there's a layer sitting above it with higher z-index that you can't see, the buttons may not be firing their onclick functions!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem as well and noticed this rule in the CSS

```
input { -webkit-appearance:none; }
```

Its purpose is to prevent iOS from applying its own styling to buttons. It also prevented the tick appearing so I moved the rule into input[type=submit], button. Problem solved.